# Using custom post template

Tags: posts, customization, templates

i'm trying to implement a custom post template for all posts filed under a specific category.

I'm making use of **WP-O-Matic plugin** that puts in the **RSS feeds in this category** and would like to make a bit of customization for the branding on posts filed under this particular category.

I found the below code from here: http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/wordpress-single-post-templates/

But when I add this to my functions.php I get a warning:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in
>   public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php(16)
>   : runtime-created function on line 1

```
add_filter( 
    'single_template', 
    create_function(
            '$t', 
            'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) 
            { 
                    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->1176}.php") ) 
                            return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->1176}.php"; 
            } 
            return $t;' 
    )
);
```

Any idea on how to figure this out.

P.S: I tried using a different approach where I made single.php as a doorway page to run a WP query. If category id matches then it renders custom-template.php else default-template.php

As mentioned [here](http://mattmedia.net/2007/10/09/how-to-set-up-custom-wordpress-category-templates-in-four-easy-steps/).

But I continue to get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in
>   public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php(16)
>   : runtime-created function on line 1
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array()
>   [function.call-user-func-array]: First
>   argument is expected to be a valid
>   callback, '' was given in
>   /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on
>   line 166

Comment: it works fine for me, what is your theme? whats the code you have at line 16 in your functions.php?

Comment: I'm using the weekly theme from themejunkie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$cat->1176` cannot be a property of an object.

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Use `$cat->term_id` and compare it’s value with the number you’re out for.

And … **don’t use anonymous functions**. They cannot be cached by opcode caches like APC and they are hard to debug – as you have seen. Plus, if someone wants to remove this filter in a child theme, that’s now very, very hard.

Comment: Thanks toscho.. I kind of figured out the problem and went ahead with option two, where single.php acts as a filter and renders the post template based on the category id.